# Need to split two SQL Server Agent Jobs into different schedules

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-agent-job

I have two SQL Agent jobs that share the same schedule due to an error I made during the creation of the second job. I generated a script in SSMS and edited some values, but I left the schedule_uid the same. Now it turns out that while those two jobs are running at the same time, they are corrupting each other's data.

What I need to do is leave the original job alone, but create a new schedule and have the second job use this new schedule. However, my searches for the correct way to do this have all resulted in dead-ends.

None of this can be done using a UI .. it all must be scripted so it can be run during a maintenance window without me present.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I'm confused about the downvote(s). Searches both here and google do not result in an answer - or at least an answer I understand. In my question I fully admit that I made an error that caused this in the first place. I am not hiding that fact or making an excuse for it. I am merely asking for some assistance in fixing what I have broken. If that earns me downvotes, so be it.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.  I upvoted it and added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use msdb.dbo.sp_detach_schedule followed by msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule.